# Losing properties when casting combobox selected item to my class

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox filled with Income or Outflow objects.
Income and Outflow are two classes that inherit from TransactionConcept.
They have a TPH EF Code First Inheritance.

```
public abstract class TransactionConcept
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class Income : TransactionConcept
{
    public virtual IncomeType IncomeType { get; set; }
}

public class Outflow : TransactionConcept
{

    public virtual OutflowType OutflowType { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentType DefaultPaymentType { get; set; }

}
```

The combobox is filled this way:

```
private void FillConcept()
    {
        IEnumerable<TransactionConcept> tConcepts;
        cmbTransactionConcept.Items.Clear();
        if (cmbTransactionType.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            var incomeRep = new IncomeRepository();
            tConcepts = incomeRep.GetAll();
            foreach (var inc in tConcepts)
            {
                cmbTransactionConcept.Items.Add(inc);
            }
        } else
        {
            var outflowRep = new OutflowRepository();
            tConcepts = outflowRep.GetAll();
            foreach (var outf in tConcepts)
            {
                cmbTransactionConcept.Items.Add(outf);
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the designer the "Description" property is selected as DisplayMember and "Id" as ValueMember.

When I do this:

```
var a = (TransactionConcept)cmbTransactionConcept.SelectedItem;
```

Only properties Id and Description are brought.

**I want to know why.**

Tried setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember to none and it changes nothing.
I think it has to be something with the virtual properties.

Comment: Why use `virtual` if you don't intend to override it? It seems strange to have `virtual` auto implemented properties...

Comment: is this in ASP.NET, WPF or anything else?

Comment: What do you mean by they're all that "are brought"? How are you checking what properties are available?

Comment: In this context virtual is not used to override the property, it's used for the Entity Framework inheritance system. This creates relationship between two classes.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver Debugging. And I mean that I can only see the value of those properties, the other are lost.

Comment: What happens if you cast it as a specific type or call a.GetType()?

Comment: I mocked up what should be able to recreate your issue [in a LinqPad script](http://share.linqpad.net/tcl3go.linq). It works fine, your issue must be some place else.

Comment: a.GetType() returns an object containing a lot of properties. The property "BaseType" contains {Name = "Income"...} wich means that the type of a is Income.

Comment: share the code of your repositories.